# GPT 2 Model on french text

Tags: natural-language

Is there someone who worked on french text generation using GPT 2 model? Is there a pre-trained GPT 2 model on french text? Can we do finetuning on the Standard GPT 2 and obtain good results on french text? Another question : Adding POS Tagging on GPT can improve the generation or not?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

> Is there someone who worked on french text generation using GPT 2 model?

I've seen two such projects:

- https://github.com/aquadzn/gpt2-french
- https://medium.com/@timohear/retraining-gpt-2-to-write-love-letters-in-french-92ae938bc452

> Is there a pre-trained GPT 2 model on french text? Can we do finetuning on the Standard GPT 2 and obtain good results on french text?

I haven't seen any available from scratch. But there are 4 separate (small) GPT2 models obtained by fine-tuning the (English) small GPT-2 model released by OpenAI on 4 different datasets: https://github.com/aquadzn/gpt2-french/releases/

Edit:
as a followup, several GPT2 model fine-tuned on French data have been contributed to HuggingFace's Models hub:

- [gpt2-french-small](https://huggingface.co/dbddv01/gpt2-french-small)
- [belgpt2](https://huggingface.co/antoiloui/belgpt2)
- [gpt2_french](https://huggingface.co/inspectorsolaris/gpt2_french)
- [gpt2_french_pre_trained](https://huggingface.co/inspectorsolaris/gpt2_french_pre_trained)